# What is data/data equivalent for Tizen

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-web-app

The installed package in android goes to /data/data folder. You can browse them through adb commands.

Can someone tell me where will the installed packages are installed in tizen? How can I browse this using sdb commands?

Answer (score 4):

As I know there are no specs about application installation directory in [Tizen specs](https://docs.tizen.org/platform/compliance/compliance-specification/).

But I know Mobile & Wearable (Z1, Z3, Gear S1, Gear S2) 2.3.x Emulator and Targets follow same rule.
For pre-installed application : `/usr/apps/[Pakcage ID]`
For User installed application : `/opt/usr/apps/[Package ID]`

And Since Tizen 3.0 has Multi User so User apps [should](https://web.archive.org/web/20200613053935/https://wiki.tizen.org/Multi-user_Platform_Metadata) be install to `/home/[user name]/apps_rw/[Package ID]`.

In Additionally, current Tizen has two type of application Web and Native.
Each Application has different installation [directory structure](https://developer.tizen.org/development/training/native-application/understanding-tizen-programming/file-system-directory-hierarchy).

Native Application

```
author-signature.xml : Author signing that created with this App
bin                  : Excutable binary or libs for App
cache                : App Cache directory use internally for platform.
data                 : Data directory that application can read or WRITE
lib                  : Libraries used in only this application.
res                  : Resources that used in only this application. 
shared               : Files (Usually resource) that can SHARED with other apps.
signature1.xml       : File signs for every files in application.
tizen-manifest.xml   : Manifest file for this Application.
```

Web Application

```
shared               : Same Usage with Native
tmp                  : It works like the browser Cache file directory
bin                  : Link of the Launcher for Web Application that Platform internal use internally.
data                 : Same Usage with Native
res                  : Same Usage with Native 
res/wgt              : Every files in User `wgt` package
```

- Icon of application (Native and Web) placed in `shared/res/` because
  it should be used to other apps.
- Files in web Application package
  (`wgt`) will be install to res/wgt.
- Message Port API use shared and
  shared/trusted internally. ([web](https://docs.tizen.org/application/web/api/2.4/device_api/mobile/tizen/messageport.html), [native](https://docs.tizen.org/application/native/api/wearable/2.3.2/group__CAPI__MESSAGE__PORT__MODULE.html))

You can't read files in directories except few things like `shared/res` if you are not root.
On Emulator or Engineering image can set root with `sdb root on` command.

Directories can be changed in any time because Tizen spec does not describe about the directories of application.